# JQuery Mobile adds weird loading message automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I've added a reference to Jquery Mobile on my website (http://www.simpleprods.com) to get the events vmousedown, vmouseup and such. I only need those, though JQuery mobile annoyingly added some ugly, automatic loading message to my web page. It's 100% coming from the JQuery mobile. **I only want vmousedown, vmouseup and vmousemove, I don't need any loading message and that orange box.** I already found out how to cancel the message but the orange box just can't be rid of.

Anyone knows what to do? **I will be glad if someone can tell me how to just get vmousedown, vmouseup and vmousemove without all the other stuff that JQuery mobile has...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rebuild jQuery Mobile framework to have only functionality you need.

Go to this site:

http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

select:

**Virtual Mouse (vmouse) Bindings**

after that just click **Build My Download**.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="jquery.mobile.custom.js"></script> 
    <script>
        $(document).on('vmousedown', '[data-role="content"]', function(){       
            alert('asdas');
        }); 
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div><p></p>

        <div data-role="content" style="height: 100px; width: 500px; background: #aabbcc;">
            <div data-role="popup" id="initialpopup" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a">Foobar</div>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

You only need to provide a **jquery.mobile.custom.js** file from builder tool.

Comment: Thank you so much, that would be helpful for me in many many situations.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't including scripts inside the `<body>` tag. That can cause the loading tag to show up when it shouldn't.